# Calling function in token contract from another contract error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

Able to call all other functions in my token contract but only on calling `sellBack ()` function it fails

```
contract LoanTokens{ 
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value);
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    function sellBack(uint tokensSelling);
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
}


contract LoanForCFL{
// some code 
}
```

but when i call

```
function testEnd(uint amount) {
    m.sellBack(amount);
}
```

got no output (no specific error message in remix) .. in mist its showing that the transaction will fail.
But when i create a new contract with only the `sellBack()` function in it,it's working fine. so confused with this ..can anyone help me out here . my `sellback` function in token code is

```
function sellBack(uint tokensSelling) external{
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= tokensSelling);
    uint totalTokensPrice = tokensSelling * tokenPrice;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= tokensSelling;
    balanceOf[owner] += tokensSelling;
    msg.sender.transfer(totalTokensPrice);
}
```

Comment: Are you are calling sellback from a truffle unit test? Make sure the balance of the sender is enough.

Comment: I am calling it from the Mist .. i have over 10000eth in that account ( private network).

Comment: But this call `function testEnd(uint amount) {
    m.sellBack(amount);
}`  is inside a unit test and the sender is the test contract.

Comment: i dint used truffel here. `function testEnd(uint amount) { m.sellBack(amount); } ` is also part of `LoanCfl`  contracts functions . it is also not working .. when i tested it in remix the controller stops at `m.sellback()` and it just stoped

Comment: The problem is when you call `m.sellBack(amount)` from `testEnd` the `msg.sender` will be LoanCfl contract and not the user. Remember that external calls change the `msg.sender`!

Comment: that is what i wanted .. my contract holds some tokens .. so in order to sell those tokens i want to send that function from my contract itself